# Help with building nested map

Tags: apex, trigger, map

I have a need to setup a structure in apex where I can specify for a Contact object and a specific set of record types, a set of fields have xyz custom roles.

For example: I want to define a structure that says:

- For a Contact object, the field TestField__c, the following record types:  RecType1, RecType2, and RecType3 are assigned the custom roles "CustomRole1, CustomRole2, CustomRole3"
- For a Contact object, the field TestField2__c, the following record types: RecType1, RecType2, and RecType3 are assigned the custom roles "CustomRole4, CustomRole5"

This is something that I need to build out as a some type of static final map in an apex class but need help on how to structure such a map.  I am not able to use a custom metadata due to some circumstances beyond my control.  Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

I took a stab at it but I don't think this will give me what I want:

```
public static final map<string, map<string, map<string, List<string>>>> myMap = new map<string, map<string, map<string, List<string>>>>  {
'Contact' => new map<string, map<string, list<string>>> {
'TestField__c' => new map<string, list<string>> {
'RecType1-RecType2-RecType3' => new List<String> {
'CustomRole1',
'CustomRole2',
'CustomRole3
}
```

My thinking is here is that when I am parsing for the RecordTypes, I can maybe strip out the dashes.

Comment: These problems get much simpler to conceptualize if you define a set of ApexTypes (classes) to represent the information structure

Comment: I think you need clarity on your requirements before you start putting them into code.  What value of TestField__c and TestField2__c would result in the 3 record types have those roles?  Try putting it into a spreadsheet before trying to make it code.